# C# Windows Form: On Close Do [Process]

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I get my windows form to do something when it is closed.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Handle the `FormClosed` event.

To do that, go to the Events tab in the Properties window and double-click the `FormClosed` event to add a handler for it.

You can then put your code in the generated `MyForm_FormClosed` handler.

You can also so this by overriding the `OnFormClosed` method; to do that, type `override onformcl` in the code window and `OnFormClosed` from IntelliSense.

If you want to be able to prevent the form from closing, handle the `FormClosing` event instead, and set `e.Cancel` to `true`.

Comment: there is no "Closed" event, only "FormClosed" - quite unintuitive

Comment: @hello_earth: There was a `Closed` event in .Net 1; it was replaced in .Net 2.0 due to various issues.  The original `Closed` event is still there for compatibility, but is hidden.

Answer (score 16):

Or another alternative is to override the OnFormClosed() or OnFormClosing() methods from System.Windows.Forms.Form.

Whether you should use this method depends on the context of the problem, and is more usable when the form will be sub classed several times and they all need to perform the same code.

Events are more useful for one or two instances if you're doing the same thing.

```
public class FormClass : Form
{
   protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
   {
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
        // Code
   } 
}
```

Comment: **And call `base.OnFormClosing(e)`.**

Comment: I would do that naturally and considered it part of the //Code comment. But indeed you're correct, probably should be in there for the lesser experienced. Thanks SLaks.

Answer (score 10):

WinForms has two events that you may want to look at.

The first, the [`FormClosing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) event, happens before the form is actually closed.  In this event, you can still access any controls and variables in the form's class.  You can also cancel the form close by setting `e.Cancel = true;` (where `e` is a [`System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs(v=VS.100).aspx) sent as the second argument to `FormClosing`).

The second, the [`FormClosed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) event, happens after the form is closed.  At this point, you can't access any controls that the form had, although you can still do cleanup on variables (such as Closing managed resources).

Comment: Updated this to use `FormClosing` and `FormClosed` as `Closing` and `Closed` are deprecated.

Comment: Is it definitely "all variables" as well as controls on the form? I tried just now and referenced 2 fields of the Form class I have (inherited from Form) and they could be accessed fine - in the FormClosed event

Comment: @PandaWood Actually, you're right.  It's just controls that are inaccessible at this point.  I'll fix it in this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Add an Event Handler to the [FormClosed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed(v=VS.100).aspx) event for your Form.

```
public class Form1
{

    public Form1()
    {    
        this.FormClosed += MyClosedHandler;
    }

    protected void MyClosedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Handle the Event here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 public FormName()
 {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.FormClosed += FormName_FormClosed;
 }

private void FormName_FormClosed(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
   //close logic here
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Syntax :

```
   form_name.ActiveForm.Close();
```

Example:

```
   {
         Form1.ActiveForm.close();
   }
```