# Show message before closing form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this Window Form and what i need is that when i close the form by pressing [x] in the window, i need to show a message.

This is not working:
Any idea why?

```
private void ControlCom_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{ 
        MessageBox.Show("test");    
}
```

I just need to display the message on button x click. But this doesn't display the message box.

Shuld i add anything else there or something? I read there is a closereason but mybe it's not the case.

Comment: You should handle form_Clothing not ControlCom_Clothing or whatever it is?

Comment: that's the name of the form

Comment: Have you checked handler in Debug mode ..Might be some exception

Comment: Try overriding the onclosing method maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/2906027/2296407

Comment: @MAL Did you change the name of the handler_method without updating in designer?

Comment: not fair I have posted ans before the person whom you accepted as answer!! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical scheme could be

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
  // If user (not system!) wants to close the form
  // but (s)he answered "no", do not close the form
  if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
    e.Cancel = MessageBox.Show(@"Do you really want to close the form?", 
                               Application.ProductName, 
                               MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No;
}
```

Comment: You should always clothe your forms, especially in this weather ;)

Comment: I liked it better before.. :(

Comment: Does this prevent the problem of shutting down the system and not closing the form because of the warning. With `CloseReason.UserClosing` by shutting down the system it wouldn't end up asking the question?

Answer (score 3):

By the way The Closing event is obsolete, it dates from .NET 1.x.  and it was replaced in .NET 2.0 with the FormClosing event.

So better try :-

```
private void ControlCom_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("test");    
}
```

For more details :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: hmm thanks, i tried it, but still, no popup message, maybe there's something overwriting it

Answer (score 3):

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure about closing the form?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: You may want to prefix this by `if(e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)`