# How to pass data back to the caller from the clickOnce applicationw

Tags: asp.net, clickonce

I have an online ClickOnce application that launches from a web page. After the application is closed, I would like the user to return information to the page. Is this possible?

I haven't found anything online. Any tips? Something that could lead me in the right direct.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just put an an action in the application's FormClose event?  If you know the application is only run from the ClickOnce webpage you could simply launch a web page on the application's FormClose event.

[Launch on Form Close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905938/c-sharp-windows-form-on-close-do-process)

[Open a URL from Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58024/open-a-url-from-windows-forms)