# Detecting that the main form was closed and abort threads

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using c# winforms to create an application. There is a thread that is activated by one of the user controls, and I want it to stop when the form is closed.
So far I have managed to deal with it if the form is closed by a button inside the app, but not if it's being closed by the x of the actual form.
How can I detect that the form is closed and then terminate the thread?
thank you.

Comment: In the form’s Close event?

Comment: Handle the FormClosed event. See this answer on another question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2905947/8104777

Comment: Note that if you set the thread's `IsBackground` property to `true`, then the thread will be terminated automatically when no other non-background threads are running. Note also that in the modern C# async/await idiom, there's almost never a good reason to create threads explicitly in the first place.